# linking from swf into source

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I just jumped into a flash-project that is making use of the feathers library. I created a swf and linked it to source. That's all fine.
But now I found a class in the feathers library that has been changed by the flash-projects delveloper. The feathers class is referencing a class in the flash-projects src.
This is producing an errror message because the swf-class can't find the class in the source.

How do I tell a feathers class in a linked swf about packages and classes in my source?

I am using Flash Builder.

Comment: A library shouldn't access classes in a local project.  You've created a dependency with the Library, you can't use the library in other projects.  I'd try to undo what ever was done and leave the library unchanged.  Remember, if the feathers library gets updated, then you have to reimplement what ever code was put in the old version.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change this setup.

Comment: You're going to have to further modify the library to access the other swfs.  I would try arguing one more time against it since as soon as you start down this path, you're stuck.